# Locators combination

Tags: protractor

I am working on protractor to test the AngularJs application. Here I came across one scenario where I want to click on image for different users. But the id for image is same for all (say 10) users. So I found one more element that is one unique number allocated to each user. The code for 2 different users are:

USER1:

```
img id="searchPatientImgAdmittedM" class="img-circle picwidth" ng-click="getPatientVitalLabPharmacy(patient.patientId._id)" onclick="ShowHide(this)" src="icons/male.png" alt="" role="button" tabindex="0"

span class="clearfloat ng-binding">12339/span
```

USER2:

```
img id="searchPatientImgAdmittedM" class="img-circle picwidth" ng-click="getPatientVitalLabPharmacy(patient.patientId._id)" onclick="ShowHide(this)" src="icons/male.png" alt="" role="button" tabindex="0"

span class="clearfloat ng-binding">8841/span
```

EDIT:

The full HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 skin-font-color paddingTop7">
    <span class="skin-font-color">
    <span class="name clearfloat ng-binding">KRISHA</span>
    <span class="clearfloat ng-binding">12348</span>
    <img id="searchPatientImgAdmittedF" class="img-circle picwidth" ng-click="getPatientVitalLabPharmacy(patient.patientId._id)" onclick="ShowHide(this)" src="icons/femaleImages.jpg" alt="" role="button" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

I tried to do :

```
element(by.id('searchPatientImgAdmittedF')).all(by.tagName('‌​12348')).click();
// or 
element(by.id('searchPatientImgAdmittedF')).element(by.tagNa‌​me('12348')).click()‌​;
```

How can I make combination of locators to click on this users. Only image part is clickable.

Comment: Can you please add, how exactly the `<span>` and `<img>` tab are related to each other. Are they on the same level below a parent-element per user? Or is `<span>` a child of `<img>`? Or the other way around? That information is relevant for providing a proper solution.

Comment: <img id="searchPatientImgAdmittedF" class="img-circle picwidth" ng-click="getPatientVitalLabPharmacy(patient.patientId._id)" onclick="ShowHide(this)" src="icons/femaleImages.jpg" alt="" role="button" tabindex="0">
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 skin-font-color paddingTop7">
<span class="skin-font-color">
<span class="name clearfloat ng-binding">KRISHA</span>
<span class="clearfloat ng-binding">12348</span>

Comment: I am trying to do : element(by.id('searchPatientImgAdmittedF')).all(by.tagName('12348')).click(); or element(by.id('searchPatientImgAdmittedF')).element(by.tagName('12348')).click();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks four your additions.

Now you're trying to click on a sister-element. There are several approaches to do so.

The one I'm usually using is:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('span.clearfloat','12348')).element(by.xpath('..')).$('#searchPatientImgAdmittedF').click();
//equal to
element(by.cssContainingText('span.clearfloat','12348')).element(by.xpath('..')).element(by.id('searchPatientImgAdmittedF')).click();
```

This evaluates first the identifiable tag with the unique number, then climbs up to its parent element, then from there gets the img-element with the ID.

- [The `$()` selector](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$)
- [The `cssContainingText()` selector](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

Another option would be to use [`isElementPresent()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent), which evaluates the existence of a child-element. However, the code is (from my point of view) more complex and I don't see, how `cssContainingText()` could be used there, so I don't try to do it here.

Comment: but again I am getting the error as :NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="searchPatientImgAdmittedF"])

Comment: what's this `*`-sign there? Do you also get some warning like "more than one element found, first element is selected"?

Comment: Failures:
1) Opne the clinicare website by logging into the site Should Add a text in username and password fields and hit login button
  Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="searchPatientImgAdmittedF"])
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="searchPatientImgAdmittedF"])
        at elementArrayFinder.getWebElements.then (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:814:27)

Comment: No I couldnt see any warning like this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick help in solving my issue. I want to add here that I found the answer to my problem and now I am able to click on the particular user I want from the list of many users. The code I am using is :

```
element(by.cssContainingText('span.clearfloat','12339'))
.element(by.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[17]/div/div/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[1]/img'))
.click();
```

This is finding the child element first and then the parent element.The id was all same for all the users so it was not taking that and so I used only xpath along with unique number.

Thanks again for the help.